# Anyone can explain the provider model in asp.net 2.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0

Preferablly with a simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spec can be found at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972319.aspx

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provider_model

> The .NET extensible provider model allows a "component" to have multiple implementations using an abstract factory pattern approach. Providers are a subclass of the ProviderBase class and typically instantiated using a factory method.

An example would be membership providers.  At runtime it works out which provider to use based on configuration settings.  The provider must adhere to a specification (defined usually by an interface).  It creates an instance of the type specified that can fulfill the requirements of the specification, and then calls methods on it to do the work.

This lets you augment and enhance default functionality to provide your own implementation (ie: custom authentication logic) using a standard interface.

Very similar to abstract factory and builder patterns.